# Annoying Visual Studio block coloring feature

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using a dark theme in Visual Studio 2010 and whenever I move the mouse to the left end of the editor it makes the whole block white, which is really annoying.

Example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40553515/strangeVS.png

How to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a VS "Feature" rather than a CodeRush one.

See if this helps...

Locate: **Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors**

Then choose **Collapsible Region** -> **Background color** and alter this value to the same as your editor background.

This should stop the color change.

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that I didn't notice this before I installed CodeRush. The color said it's "automatic", which was black, but when I changed to black, and tried to change back to "automatic" now it was white. Strange.